# Is there a non-singular cubic surface that has a point where four lines intersect?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, complex-manifolds

Every non-singular complex projective cubic surface has $27$ lines. Many such surfaces contain points where three lines intersect (called Eckardt points). There are even surfaces with many Eckardt points, like the Fermat cubic, which has $18$. Is there any such non-singular complex projective cubic surface where four, five, or six lines intersect at a point?

[Post on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585682/is-there-a-non-singular-cubic-surface-that-has-a-point-where-four-lines-intersec)

Comment: From the title it sounds like you’re asking if all nonsingular cubic surfaces have such a point, but from the post it sounds like you’re asking if there exists even one such surface.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  No, there is no such cubic surface.  Consider the intersection of the cubic surface with the osculating hyperplane at the point.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this in an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  If p is a smooth point on any surface S, and is
contained in a line l on S, then l is contained in the tangent plane at p,
call it T_p.  Now if S is a cubic then it intersects T_p in a cubic curve
(with some singularity at p, even though S is smooth at p); and a cubic curve
can contain at most three lines.

Comment: This was very helpful.